# Does the German PS3 support UK games?

Tags: ps3, region-lock

Does the German PS3 support UK games?

Answer (score 11):

Yes

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout) :

> The PlayStation 3 is one of the few home consoles to be advertised as region-free.  However, while **region free for PS3 games**, there is region locking for backwards compatible PS2 and PS1 games, as well as DVD and Blu-ray Disc movies. Additionally, some games separate online players per region, such as Metal Gear Solid 4 Online.

Comment: Another thing you have to be careful with is Downloadable Content (DLC) - for example the US version of Rock Band plays perfectly on my Australian PS3, but I can't download songs for it from the Australian PlayStation store.

Comment: Many UK games are even playable completely with german language support. It only depends on the provided languages on the Disc.

Comment: yup, same problem for dragon age DLC :(

Comment: @jwaddell: That's true, but in this case Germany and the UK are both serviced by the same Playstation store (ie the European/PAL one) and so have compatible DLC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Playing UK games on a german console was never a problem because it's the same region anyway (same goes for DVDs and Blu-ray discs).

I use my german PS3 with games bought in the UK regularly and never encountered any problems regarding DLC. Most games you get from the UK are the "european" version which also has the german version built in.